# Regex - how to get time and date and get ISO8601 timestamp

Tags: regex

I have this text

```
2014-01-30 10:15 some text here
2014-01-30 10:20 some other text here
```

I need a regex that matches a timestamp group in ISO 8601 format.

Required output:

```
2014-01-30T10:15Z
2014-01-30T10:20Z
```

With this REGEX I can't get what I want, replace the space with 'T' and append a 'Z at the end.

```
^(?<timestamp>\S+ \S+)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**--- UPDATE ---**

BTW, I'm using http://rubular.com/ to test my regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps modify your current regex a bit to:

```
^(\S+) (\S+).*
```

And replace with `$1T$2Z`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/jV5gR4)

Comment: You've inverted `T` and `Z` ;-o

Comment: @M42 Oopsie... D: Fixed now, thank you for noticing!

Comment: What about "ლ(ಠ_ಠლ) ლ(ಠ_ಠლ)"? Doesn't look like a timestamp to me.

Comment: @tenub Maybe not, but neither does `౨౩౨౩-౨౩-౨౩ ౨౩:౨౩`. My point is, I'm pretty sure that OP will always have strings of that specific format and that's why they used `\S+` in the first place.

Comment: Some people use non-latin numbers, don't be so biased. Also, he did specify: "I need a regex that matches a timestamp group in ISO 8601 format."

Answer (score 1):

`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}` will match the required format – validation is another story though (if you need it).

You can do something like `if (regex match) { replace " " with "T"; append "Z" }`

If this doesn't help you or it is unclear it is because your question was vague.

Edit: you didn't specify what language you're writing this in. That is how you would do your replacements.

Comment: I want a REGEX that do the replace job

Comment: Regex doesn't do the replacement, it only matches. Then you need code that does the replacement part.

Answer (score 1):

In php:

```
preg_replace('/^(\S+) (\S+).*/', "$1T$2Z", $str);
```

In perl:

```
$str =~ s/^(\S+) (\S+).*/$1T$2Z/;
```

In notepad++

Find what: `^(\S+) (\S+).*`
Replace with: `$1T$2Z`

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})( \d{2}:\d{2} )(?:.*)
```

You can capture 2014-01-30 10:15 in groups (and ignore the text in another group).

Then you use the second group (10:15) to add 'T' at the beginning and 'Z' at the end.

See demo at:
http://rubular.com/r/4icGfcIixa

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a bit different from language to language, it could help if you told us what language you are using.
For example, in javascript, you can do something like this:

```
"2014-01-30 10:15 some text here".replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2})\s?.*/,"$1T$2Z")
```

Where the string can be a variable.

If you have a multiple line text them you should add a `g` at the end of the regex:

```
"2014-01-30 10:15 some text here\n2014-01-30 10:20 some other text here".replace(/.*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2})\s?.*/g,"$1T$2Z")
```